# Aws Glue: how to persist a DynamicFrame

Tags: aws-glue

Is there a way to persist a DynamicFrame in Glue as you do in Spark with dataframe.cache() or dataframe.persist()?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, currently there is no way to persist DynamicFrame directly. However, you can convert it to DataFrame and use `df.persist()` or `df.cache()` and then convert it back to DynamicFrame if needed:

```
val df = dynamicFrame.toDF()
val cachedDf = df.persist()
val dynamicFrameCached = DynamicFrame(cachedDf, glueContext)
```